# flotr2 chart showing blank screen on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, flotr2

I want to display flotr2 chart on my iOS device.
I have created UIWebView and trying to call the index.html page but it's showing me blank page.

I have also added flotr2.min.js file in my project.
Here is my html code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        #container {
            width : 600px;
            height: 384px;
            margin: 8px auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="flotr2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {             
            var
            container = document.getElementById('container'),
            start = (new Date).getTime(),
            data, graph, offset, i;

         // Draw a sine curve at time t
         function animate (t) {

            data = [];
            offset = 2 * Math.PI * (t - start) / 10000;

         // Sample the sine function
         for (i = 0; i < 4 * Math.PI; i += 0.2) {
            data.push([i, Math.sin(i - offset)]);
         }

         // Draw Graph
         graph = Flotr.draw(container, [ data ], {
            yaxis : {
                max : 2,
                min : -2
            }
         });

         // Animate
         setTimeout(function () {
            animate((new Date).getTime());
         }, 50);
     }

     animate(start);
 })();
</script>
</body>
```

Note: When i try this code in separate folder then it's working fine.

Comment: Check that `flotr2.min.js` is added under **Copy Bundle Resources** and not under **Compile Sources**

Comment: I have already checked that….

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you should pass baseURL parameter like this:

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:someHTML baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
```